# PHP - for statement in a string

Tags: php, mysql, string, for-loop

I have a MySQL statement that I want to execute and inside this statement I would like to include a for loop to define the columns that data will be entered into etc.

The code I currently have is

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT into DATA ('.
    for($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++) {
        echo $columns[$i];
    }
    .') VALUES ('.
    for($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++) {
       echo ':'.$columns[$i].' , ';
    }
    .')');
```

Obviously this doesn't work but if it was to work also in the second for statement it echos a comma at the end of each loop, which will cause an error for the last loop so also is there a way to fix this to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u may use implode instead of for loop with ',' separator. Can you please echo the query and check if query works fine
 in columns you are probably printing values instead of column names .. just "echo $i;" using foreach

Comment: make new variable $prepare="INSERT INTO data ("; and then in for loop add your data to taht variable

Comment: You can use `implode` function.

Comment: @DeiForm Could you please explain more?

Comment: see the answer, smh like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$sql = "INSERT into DATA (`"  . implode('`,`', $columns) . "`) values (:" . implode(',:', $columns) . ")"
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Example result:

```
// Input array
$columns = array('A', 'B', 'C');

// Output
INSERT into DATA(`A`,`B`,`C`) values (:A,:B,:C)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [join/implode](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.join.php) function:

```
$params = array_map(function($var){return ':'.$var;}, $columns);
$sql = 'INSERT into DATA ('.join(',', $columns).') VALUES ('.join(',', $params).')';    
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the query **outside** of the prepare() function to make it easier.

Something like that would be better/clearer :

```
$count = count ($columns); // Avoid using count in your loop init (Performances)
$query = 'INSERT INTO DATA (' .
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $query .= $columns[$i];
}
$query .= ') VALUES (';
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   if ($i != $count - 1) $query.= ':'.$columns[$i].' , ';
   else $query .= ':'.$columns[$i]; // No coma for the last value
}
$query .= ')';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
```